# Is it possible to use expo splash screen on a react-native-cli inited project

Tags: react-native, expo, splash-screen, react-native-cli

Let's assume I have a project in React Native which was inited with react-native-cli. Is it possible to use expo's splash screen to this project?

And if not what is the best way to implement a splash screen in a React Native project that was created with react-native-cli?

(besides react-native-splash-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisited this after two years.

Right now the best way to do that is [react-native-bootsplash](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash)